# Next.js seems to cache files as in a route of _next/data/[path].json preventing getStaticProps from running in server side render

Tags: graphql, next.js, apollo, server-side-rendering, vercel

The issue appears to happen when I post the link on platforms like Discord and Slack, where then to produce a URL preview they send a request to the link. The link which in this case follows this structure (normal format) [www.domain.com/ctg/[...ids]](http://www.domain.com/ctg/%5B...ids%5D).

[image]

Within `[...ids]` I either pass one of two ids for the same object, the object has the following structure:

```
type Catalogue {
  id: ID!
  edit_id: String!
  user_id: String!
  title: String
  ...
}
```

The first id I could pass into [...ids] would be `Catalogue.id`
The second id I could pass into [...ids] would be `Catalogue.edit_id`

Whenever either of those inputs for [...ids] is passed as part of a request the following `getStaticProps` is ran:

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const { ids } = params;
  let catalogue: CatalogueType | null = await fetchFullCatalogue(ids[0]);
  return {
    props: {
      catalogue_prop: catalogue,
      params,
    },
  };
};
```

with `fetchFullCatalogue` being:

```
export const fetchFullCatalogue = async (
  id: string
): Promise<CatalogueType | null> => {
  let catalogue: CatalogueType;
  const fetchToUrl =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
      ? "http://localhost:4000/graphql"
      : process.env.BACKEND_URL + "/graphql";
  // create a axios fetch request to the http://localhost:4000/graphql
  const query = `
  <...SOME FRAGMENTS LATER...>
  fragment AllCatalogueFields on Catalogue {
    id
    edit_id
    user_id
    status
    title
    description
    views
    header_image_url
    header_color
    author
    profile_picture_url
    event_date
    location
    created
    updated
    labels {
      ...AllLabelFields
    }
    listings {
      ...AllListingFields
    }
  }
  query Catalogues($id: ID, $edit_id: String) {
    catalogues(id: $id, edit_id: $edit_id) {
      ...AllCatalogueFields
    }
  }`;

  const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    method: "post",
    url: fetchToUrl,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({
      query,
      variables: { id: id, edit_id: id },
    }),
  };
  let response = await axios(config);
  if (response.data.errors) return null;

  catalogue = response.data.data.catalogues[0];
  console.log("catalogue", catalogue);
  return catalogue;
};
```

The request it is making is to the following API endpoint

```
  Query: {
    catalogues: async (
      _: null,
      args: { id: string; edit_id: string }
    ): Promise<Catalogue[]> => {
      let catalogues: Catalogue[];

      // when both id and edit_are passed
      if (args.id && args.edit_id) {
        catalogues = await getFullCatalogues(args.id, "id", true);
        // the following convoluted request is the result of
        // me responding to the fact that only the edit_id was working
        if (catalogues.length === 0) {
          catalogues = await getFullCatalogues(args.edit_id, "edit_id", true);
          if (catalogues.length === 0) {
            throw new UserInputError("No catalogues found");
          }
        } else {
          catalogues = await getFullCatalogues(
            catalogues[0].edit_id,
            "edit_id",
            true
          );
        }
        console.log("catalogues", catalogues);
      } else if (args.id) {
        catalogues = await getFullCatalogues(args.id);
      } else if (args.edit_id) {
        catalogues = await getFullCatalogues(args.edit_id, "edit_id");
      } else {
        const res = await db.query(fullCatalogueQuery());
        catalogues = res.rows;
      }

      return catalogues;
    },

    ...
  },
```

This results in the following output within the deployed logs:

[image]

The logs show the data when the `Catalogue` is first created which simultaneously navigates me to the URL of "normal format" with `Catalogue.id` which is interpreted as `/_next/data/qOrdpdpcJ0p6rEbV8eEfm/ctg/dab212a0-826f-42fb-ba21-6ebb3c1350de.json`. This contains the default data when `Catalogue` is first generated with `Catalogue.title` being "Untitled List"

Before sending both requests I changed the `Catalogue.title` to "asd".

Notice how the request with the `Catalogue.edit_id` which was sent as the "normal format" was interpreted as `/ctg/ee0dc1d7-5458-4232-b208-1cbf529cbf4f?edit=true`. This resulted in the correct data being returned with `Catalogue.title` being "asd".

Yet the following request with the `Catalogue.id` although being of the same "normal format" never provoked any logs.

(I have tried sending the request without the params `?edit=true` and the same happens)

Another important detail is that the (faulty) request with the `Catalogue.id` produces the (faulty) URL preview much faster than the request with `Catalogue.edit_id`.

My best theory as to why this is happening is that the data of the URL with `Catalogue.id` is somehow stored/cached. This would happen as the `Catalogue` is first created. In turn it would result in the old stored `Catalogue.id` being returned instead of making the fetch again. Whereas the `Catalogue.edit_id` makes the fetch again.

Refrences:

Live site: https://www.kuoly.com/

Client: https://github.com/CakeCrusher/kuoly-client

Backend: https://github.com/CakeCrusher/kuoly-backend

Anything helps, I felt like ive tried everything under the sun, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I learned that For my purposes I had to use `getServerSideProps` instead of `getStaticProps`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).